# How do I write "text as fractions" without moving to the next line in the O/P?

Tags: fractions, inline

I used this command to get (a+b+c)/2

```
x=\[\frac{\textrm{a+b+c}}{2}\]
```

However, the output has shifted it to the next line, as shown

[image]

Is there a way I can have this in-line with the text?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Do you want *all* maths in your paper to feature "math as text" behavior, or just this one  particular formula?

Comment: @Mico, no just this formula.

Answer (score 3):

You asked,

> Is there a way I can have this in-line with the text?

Yes: Replace `\[` and `\]` with `\(` and `\)`. The former pair initiates and terminates display-math mode, and the latter initiates and terminates inline-math mode. Oh, and I would use `\mathrm`, not `\textrm`.

Summing up: Just write

```
... where \(\mathrm{x}=\frac{\mathrm{a+b+c}}{2}\).
```

or, better still,

```
... where \(\mathrm{x}=(\mathrm{a+b+c})/2\).
```

In the final expression, I've replaced the bulky `\frac`-style notation with inline-fraction notation.

Comment: Thank you so much, the change of brackets worked.